# determine the validity of 2 statements about stationary points

Tags: calculus

The graph of ${= f(x)}$ shown has stationary points at (0, p) and (q, r).  Here are 2 statements about ${f(x)}$.

(1)  ${f(x) < 0}$ for ${s < x < t;}$

(2)  ${f'(x) < 0}$ for ${x < p}$

Which of the following is true

A Neither statement is correct.

B Only statement (1) is correct.

C Only statement (2) is correct.

D Both statements are correct

[image]

So I would say only statement 2 is correct because if ${{dy\over dx} < 0}$ then the curve is decreasing and s and t appear on the x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only statement $1$ is correct. When $s<x<t$, clearly $f(x)<0$ as it lies below the line $y = 0$. Statement $2$ is false since $f'(0) = 0$ and $0<q$.

Comment: $f'(0)=0$ because it's stationary there

Comment: When a curve is decreasing, there can be also points with $f'(x)=0$!!!

Comment: @sigmabe edited :)

Comment: It's also wrong with stricty decreasing. In the exercise also stands $f'(0)=0$ so statement (2) is false.

Comment: Whoops, I read q as p. I will fix the answer.